# Como invertir el orden de un ngFor

Tags: firebase, ionic, angular

Yo traigo la información de un `json` que genero con firebase, y la imprimo con un `ngFor`, pero este siempre imprime el arreglo del primero al ultimo, yo quisiera hacerlo al contrario.

Así obtengo los datos

```
    obtenerdatos(){
    return this.http.get('https://informacion.json');
  }


ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.proveedor.obtenerdatos()
    .subscribe(
      (data)=> {this.rutas = data;},
      (error)=>{console.log(error);}
    )
  }
```

Aquí los muestro:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let ruta of rutas">

<img src="{{ruta.tarjeta}}">
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="pin" item-start large></ion-icon>
  <h2>Punto de encuentro:</h2>
  <p>{{ruta.puntodeencuentro}}</p>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="calendar" item-start large></ion-icon>
  <h2>Fecha:</h2>
  <p>{{ruta.fecha}}</p>
</ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrías simple y sencillamente invertir el orden del arreglo con el método `reverse`

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.proveedor.obtenerdatos()
  .subscribe(
    (data)=> {this.rutas = data.reverse();},
    (error)=>{console.log(error);}
  )
}
```

Comment: Hola, pero de donde traigo ese método?

Comment: es un método de javascript que sirve para invertir un arreglo, no se a que te refieres con donde lo traigo

Comment: me parece un error cuando lo trato de utilizar :"La propiedad reverse no existe en el tipo object"

Comment: entonces eso significa que no es un array, es un objeto y estas iterando sobre las propiedades de ese objeto

Comment: oh no amigo, si me funciono muchas gracias, el editor me marca un error pero cuando lo compilo me funciona muy bien. muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada estimado